# how force deleting docker image affects existing containers using it

Tags: docker

When i try to delete an image via `docker rmi` that has an existing container, i get an error message. ( normal )

When i add force flag `docker rmi -f` the image is deleted and when i check containers state using `docker ps -a`the container is still there but image namebecomes an ID.

So my question, from where comes this ID ? Is it a copy of the image that is kept in the cache and used for existing containers cause when i check `docker images` i find an image with  in repo and  in name and its ID is the one that is newly affected to old existing containers.

Another question that follows : 
Once a container is created, is changing anything on the existing ( local ) image affecting in any way the existing containers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A docker image has a name and an image ID. This [blog](http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/) describes where the image ID is comming from in pre-docker-v1.10 and after it.

If you perform docker rmi -f image of an image which is used by a running container you're actually not deleting the real image but deleting the name and tag on the image.

So indeed `docker ps` will show:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
578e28246977        96931e4c66bd        "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   drunk_shannon
```

But `docker images` is still showing your image:

```
<none>                          <none>              96931e4c66bd        6 weeks ago         711.9 MB
```

It's just untagged. The image isn't also deleted after you delete this container. The image remains in the list. You can start new containers from it with `docker run -d 96931e4c66bd` (by using the ID)

You can even retag it:

```
docker tag 96931e4c66bd my-jenkins:1.0
```

Than `docker images` shows:

```
my-jenkins                      1.0                 96931e4c66bd        6 weeks ago         711.9 MB
```

> Another question that follows : Once a container is created, is
>   changing anything on the existing ( local ) image affecting in any way
>   the existing containers ?

No, when you make an "update" on your image (same name), the running container will probably lose it's image-name (only has an ID, just like when you're deleting your image during the container is running). 
You'll need to reexecute the run-command with the new image (which will have another image-ID after the update) to have a container running from the newest image.

Comment: That confirms my thoughts. Thanks.